# shinyapps.io does not draw plots

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinyapps

I  built a simple app using FactorMineR package to do MCA analysis and clustering depending on selected variables.

The app works fine on my local device, however it does not show any plots (either base plots and ggplots) on shinyapps.io server. I checked the packages and locally and remotley they are the same. I also checked if the MCA() function from FactoMineR pcg even works by extracking some results and rendering them as a table what gave positive results. So there is only the problem with plots drawing. I have been trying to solve it for two days but nothing helps so I am asking you for any advice.

Here is how it looks locally: [image: mca_locally]

Here is the link to the app: https://mikolajm.shinyapps.io/MCA_test/

And a reproducible example

```
library(shiny)
library(FactoMineR)
library(cluster)
library(ggplot2)
data(tea)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("MCA"),
  textOutput("packages"),br(),
  tableOutput("table"),br(),

  fluidRow(
    column(4, checkboxGroupInput("Variables", "Select variables:", 
                                 names(tea), selected=c("breakfast", "tea.time"))),
    column(4, plotOutput("plot")), column(4, plotOutput("plot1"))),
  fluidRow(column(12, plotOutput("dendro", height = "700px", width="1200px"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## packages checking
  output$packages <- renderText({.packages()})
  tea_selected <- reactive({
    tea[, input$Variables]
  })

  ## table with some results from MCA() fun
  output$table <- renderTable({
    tea.mca <- MCA(tea_selected(), ncp=9)
    tea.mca$eig[1:5,]

  })

  ##  mca1
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    library(FactoMineR)
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
   tea.mca <- MCA(tea_selected(), ncp=9)
  })


  ## mca with ggplot
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    tea.mca <- MCA(tea_selected(), ncp=9)
    tea_vars_df <- data.frame(tea.mca$var$eta2, Variable =names(tea_selected())) 

    library(ggplot2)

    pp <- ggplot(data=tea_vars_df, aes(x=Dim.1, y=Dim.2, label=Variable))+
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
      geom_point()+
      geom_text() +
      ggtitle("MCA plot of variables ")+
      theme_bw()

    pp
    })
  ### dendro 

  output$dendro <- renderPlot({
    library(FactoMineR)
    library(cluster)

    tea.mca <- MCA(tea_selected(), ncp=9)
    classif <- agnes(tea.mca$ind$coord,method="ward")
    plot(classif,main="Dendrogram",ask=F,which.plots=2)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Did you upload your data with the R code? Could you show the commands you used for uploading your `app.R` and your data to shinyapps.io? If it works locally, the easiest explanation is that you are missing the data on shinyapps.io.

Comment: I uploaded my code (the one that is in my post) using rstudio publish button. The data(tea) are included to the factominer package. The checkbox imports the variables from this data, and they are shown on the webpage but not the plots. So I think it is not a data issue.

Comment: Each time shiny runs on apps.io, an R session must run it. Are you sure the R environment on the R shiny server has `FactoMineR`? Add `textOutput("packages")` to your `ui` and `output$packages <- renderText({.packages()})` to your `server`. Try it locally, it should print the packages loaded in your environment. Then try it on apps.io...

Comment: I added your code and packages loaded both locally and remotely are the same and the FactoMiner is beeing loaded. I also checked if the MCA() function even works by extracting its results and rendering a table what gave positive results. So the problem must be somewhere with the graphs. I updated the code in my post with those new functions

Comment: @MikolajM I tested deployment and checked the log in shinyapps.io. There are these lines: 2017-06-16T20:01:20.810740+00:00 shinyapps[189841]: dev.new(): using pdf(file="Rplots1.pdf")
... So it looks like the plot go to pdf output instead of rendered img. There are several plots in your app, you can only enable one of them and test again to locate the problem. One thing I noticed is the `p` in `output$plot`, what is that? typo?

Comment: And when you are using ggplot, you should not use `plot()` on ggplot object. Just return the ggplot object, which will be rendered. This is probably the root cause of problem.

Comment: I removed this but it's still having same problem. Somewhere in your code must changed the default plot device to pdf.

Comment: You can also ask in the google groups of shinyapps.io, since this could be some problem in their end.

Comment: @dracodoc thanks for advice. yes the `p` in `output$plot` was just a typo. I also removed the `plot()` from the ggplot object section. Inspired your notice about the log I did some googling and found this [link](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/494) however adding `pdf(NULL)` didnt help

Comment: Yes I also tried that. I suggest you to ask in shinyapps.io user google groups.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: You can see plots obviously**, but

**ORIGINAL**
I could not see plots in your shiny app when I ran your code.

After some digging, my guess is only that:

You use a lot of functions that come with the `FactoMineR` package. For instance, you use the function `MCA` in `output$plot1` code block. Type `MCA` in your R command line, and it should print the function. You can see `MCA` does a lot of stuff and eventually calls `plot.MCA`. Now type `plot.MCA` in your R command line. You can see that `plot.MCA` has a lot of `plot` commands, and I'm pretty sure this executes all the plotting when you call `MCA`. I think your problem is that `plot` in the function `plot.MCA` is sent to the graphic device, and these plots are not saved, ie they are not `return()` to the `parent` environment. **This is only speculation.**

Comment: I added a screenshot of the app in my post. I will try to work it out with the return() function

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea...I did not see these plots when I ran your code however. I'll update my answer to indicate you can see plots but I can't.